# Python Django POST request to different views

Tags: python, django, post

In Python Django, I sent a POST request to one view, called view1, and want to see that same POST request in another view, called view2.

I tried to import that view1's method into view2, yet I just got that view1's method when doing a GET request to view2, not a POST request from view1 and seeing it in view2.

view1.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
  if "POST" == request.method:
    list_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

  elif "GET" == request.method:
    list_data = serialize('json', ApiStatus.objects.all())

  return HttpResponse(list_data, content_type='application/json')
```

view2.py

```
from app.views.view1 import index

def status(request):  
    print("STATUS request method ", request) # gives a GET request when reloading page
    print("INDEX method from view1.py ", index) # shows when doing GET request
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

post_file.py

```
def get_test_req():
    return { 'Samurai': 'Masamune'}

def post_data():
        data = []
        data.append(get_test_req())
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(view1_url, headers=headers, json=data, timeout=10.0)
```

Expected: To see post request from view1 into view2 after posting to view1.

Actual: I only see a GET request in view2 and showing view1 as an imported value.

Comment: You can only post to a single URL. Any redirects won't carry the payload. If you explain what you are trying to achieve we might come up with an alternative method.

Comment: Hmm, it's alittle more detailed of what I want to do which includes using ROS (Robot Operating System). In view2, if I saw that view1 did a POST which updates values in a database, I can see that data was changed into my database which will be reflected in view2's url. View2 url shows a table of values. View2 uses ROS, if there is a post request, ROS will initiate it's node and service. A solution could be just to do it all in view2, but I wanted to leave view1 alone and just do all the ROS manipulations in view2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a work around. Instead of looking for different post requests, in my initial post request in the first view, I added values to a database.

In the second view, I did a GET request and then checked if values were updated in a database in the last minute. If there were values in the queryset, I'd initialize the ROS node with code as follows:

view2.py

```
def status(request):
    right_now = datetime.now()
    last_time = right_now - timedelta(seconds=20)
    last_min_data = ApiStatus.objects.values().filter(date_time__gte=last_time)

    if last_min_data.exists():
        logging.debug("\n \n last_min_data EXISTS \n \n")

        rospy.init_node('root')
        s = rospy.Service('ros_post', OneInt, handle_request)
```

If there is a better solution, I'm certainly open to hearing it. Thanks.